# React router - code splitting lazy imports. Switch with Suspense outside

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, webpack-module-federation

I'm using module federation from webpack and my core app contained all routes to the rest of the app. What works fine is that inside the `Switch`, I just had each `AuthRoute` or `Route` manually rather than using the `map`. `Suspense` was wrapping the Switch so that the direct children are just `Route`.  I'm now doing some splitting but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

my routes are set up as so (and localRoutes is at the bottom):

```
const routes = [
  ...localRoutes,
  // ...remoteRoutes
];
```

Inside my `BrowserRouter` I map routes based on whether the user is authorised for that route or not. I suspect the problem is here but don't understand why `Route` or `AuthRoute` that returns a `Route` won't work since it's a directly under the `Switch`.

```
  <Switch>
    {routes.map((route) => {
      console.log(route)
      route.auth ?
        <AuthRoute
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          component={route.component}
          exact={route.exact}
          requiredRoles={route.requiredRoles}
        />
        :
        <Route
          key={route.path}
          path={route.path}
          component={route.component}
          exact={route.exact}
        />
    })}
    <Redirect to='/login' />
  </Switch>
```

where authRoute:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ Component, path, exact, requiredRoles }) => {
    const isLoggedIn = true // or false
    const roles = ['admin', 'sth_else']
    const userHasRequiredRole = intersection(requiredRoles, roles).length > 0
    const message = userHasRequiredRole ? 'Please log in to view this page' : "You can't be here!"
    return (
        <Route
            exact={exact}
            path={path}
            render={(props) =>
                isLoggedIn && userHasRequiredRole 
                    ? (
                        <Component {...props} />
                    ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: userHasRequiredRole ?
                                    '/login' :
                                    '/modules',
                                state: {
                                    message,
                                    requestedPath: path
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default AuthRoute;
```

and example routes:

```
const AboutPage = lazy(() => import('core/AboutPage'))
const LoginPage = lazy(() => import('core/LoginPage'))
const MyModules = lazy(() => import('core/MyModules'))

const routes = [
  {
    auth: true,
    path: "/modules",
    component: MyModules,
    exact: false,
    requiredRoles: [
        String(UserRoles.Administrator),
        String(UserRoles.AnotherRole),
        String(UserRoles.Another)
      ]
  },
  {
    auth: false,
    path: "/about",
    component: AboutPage,
    exact: false,
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing lazyLoad specify component as a function inside `<Route>`.

In your case try the following:

```
 <Route
     key={route.path}
     path={route.path}
     component={(props) => (<route.component {...props} />)}
     exact={route.exact}
 />
```

Comment: funny, I had that on the AuthRoute component (which handles that) and not the Route component that needed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

I think the above code should work if you add a return before ternary operator

```
retur route.auth ?...
```

I am having  similar structure in my app

```
<Suspense fallback={<Spinner  />}>
          <Switch>
            <Refresh path="refresh" />
            {routes.map((route) => {
              return <PrivateRoute key={route.path} {...route} user={user} />;
            })}
            {routes.length && user && <Route component={NotFound} />}
          </Switch>
        </Suspense>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.